# Getting error: Unable to open merge module '...msm'. Check to make sure the module language is correct

Tags: wix, merge-module

My goal is to include the OPC COM ProxyStub MergeModule (x64) in my msi.  I am using WiX.  I tried following the example code for [How To: Install the Visual C++ Redistributable with your installer](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_vcredist.html).

Here is my Product.wxs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" ...>
  <Product Id="*" Name="..." Language="1033" Version="..." Manufacturer="..." UpgradeCode="...">
    ...  
    <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
        <Merge Id="OPCRedist" SourceFile="OPC COM ProxyStub MergeModule (x64).msm" DiskId="1" Language="0"/>
    </DirectoryRef>
    <Feature Id="OPCRedist" Title="OPC Core Components" AllowAdvertise="no" Display="hidden" Level="1">
        <MergeRef Id="OPCRedist"/>
    </Feature>
  </Product>
  ...
</Wix>
```

When I compile the wixproj I get the following error:

> Unable to open merge module 'OPC COM ProxyStub MergeModule (x64).msm'. Check to make sure the module language is correct. 'The language of this installation package is not supported by your system. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070657)'

How do I get rid of that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `Language="0"` to `Language="1033"` got rid of the error.  I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: Good thanks for that. I tested my installer and it indeed put it in the right place.

Comment: Note: `1033` means **English** (en-US) ... If somebody wants to include a merge module of an **other language**, the code must match. For example German (de-DE) is `1031` ... Here is a code table. Look to column "LCID Decimal". https://www.science.co.il/language/Locale-codes.php